# how to create multiple one plot that contains all my plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatter = ax.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['rain'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax.set_xlabel('area')
ax.set_ylabel('rain')
plt.colorbar(scatter)


fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
scatter = ax.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['wind'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax1.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax1.set_xlabel('area')
ax1.set_ylabel('wind')
plt.colorbar(scatter)
plot.show()
```

this code creates two separate plots, i want to create one plot that contains both of these.i left an image of how the plots appear. Help would be appreciated, thanks

[image: 2 plots]

a suggested solution was to avoid plotting twice and using subplots instead, but this causes the 2 graphs to bisect each other any suggested fixes?

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
scatter = ax.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['rain'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax.set_xlabel('area')
ax.set_ylabel('rain')
plt.colorbar(scatter)



ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
scatter = ax.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['wind'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax1.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax1.set_xlabel('area')
ax1.set_ylabel('wind')
plt.colorbar(scatter)
```

[image: plot problem]

Comment: Note that you have a mistake when you plot your second scatter. You should call scatter function on ax1, but you did call the function on ax.

Comment: yes i think @AminGheibi suggested a solution to the problem of calling when plotting twice, but when doing what he suggested i run into another problem in which the graphs arent properly oriented.

Comment: The orientation is the same. You need to increase the size of the figure when you create it by ```fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))```. You know because you have two plots in one figure there are less space and you should make space. These two numbers in ```figsize``` function determines the width and height of the figure. If you want your figure wider, you can increase 8.

Comment: Also you have an error in this part of the code:  ```ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
scatter = ax.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['wind'],c=kmeans[0],s=50)```. You need to plot into ```ax1``` but you did it in ```ax```.

Comment: The error is in line 13.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subplots. Instead of making different figures you can call `add_subplot` on the same figure.

You make a figure by the following code and get a handle to a figure:

```
fig = plt.figure()
```

Then you determine the number of rows and columns of plots inside that figure by a number that you pass to the `add_subplot` function. For example, if you want a layout of one row and two columns the first two digits in the argument is 12 and the third digit determines which cell:

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122)
```

So, your code will be like this:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
scatter = ax.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['rain'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax.set_xlabel('area')
ax.set_ylabel('rain')
plt.colorbar(scatter)


ax1 = fig.add_subplot(122)
scatter = ax1.scatter(wh1['area'],wh1['wind'],
                     c=kmeans[0],s=50)
ax1.set_title('K-Means Clustering')
ax1.set_xlabel('area')
ax1.set_ylabel('wind')
plt.colorbar(scatter)
plot.show()
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, this solution kinda works but it causes other problems. the graphs are intersecting each other the 2nd plot doesnt even show the clusters. any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: i edited the question and left an image of whats happening when i run this

Comment: If you want to make some space between subplot (to remove intersecting axis) you can use subplot_adjust function: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html

Comment: Regarding the issue that the second plot does not show anything, I've mentioned above. You have an error in line 13. Please see the comments below your question.